# Nested queries with distinct and max

Tags: mongodb

I'm teaching myself MongoDB, and I have read and tried basic queries. Now, I'm trying to perform more complex ones. For example, I'm have been trying to convert:

```
SELECT distinct(Location) FROM Place WHERE Frequency=(SELECT MAX(distinct(Frequency)) from Place);
```

but I'm having a hard time combining everything despite many tries and looking at the official docs and other SO posts. Honestly, I was gonna post my attempts, but they're so off from the correct query that it's useless since I have no clue where to begin combining.

Can anyone please show me the converted query and explain the various components?

Comment: Look into aggregation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Klaus.dk](https://klaus.dk/sqltomongodb/) and [Query translator](http://www.querymongo.com/). They are good site for converting sql queries to mongodb systax

Comment: I have already. Unfortunately, both don't support nested queries like I'm using. Thanks for the suggestion though